# How to get moodle course completion status

Tags: moodle

I want to get course completion states in a moodle i enable the completion for site and for course and activities and set conditions to it.i can get activities completion  form `mdl_course_modules_completion` DB table now i want get course completion i look in `mdl_course_completions` and `mdl_course_completion_criteria`
tables but no records found.,is there any moodle inbuilt function for this

i tried follwing code also but did find a good result

```
require_once("{$CFG->libdir}/completionlib.php");
$cinfo = new completion_info(51);
$iscomplete = $cinfo->is_course_complete($USER->id);
var_dump($iscomplete);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me

```
              require_once("{$CFG->libdir}/completionlib.php");
              $course = new stdClass();
              $course->id = 51;
              $cinfo = new completion_info($course);
              $iscomplete = $cinfo->is_course_complete($USER->id);
              var_dump($iscomplete);
```

Answer (score 0):

the parameter to give is the course object

`global $COURSE;`

completionlib.php :

```
 /*
 * @param stdClass $course Moodle course object.
 */
public function __construct($course) {
    $this->course = $course;
    $this->course_id = $course->id;
}
```